How to catch a failure of "here-string" command?
As far as I understand, the following bash-script should be aborting after the second statement, because the command meant to initialize the variable a fails:
set -eu -o pipefail

read a <<< $(false)

echo Hi there: '>'$a'<'

Instead the variable is assigned an empty string and the script proceeds to print: Hi there: ><.
How can I reliably -- distinguishing actual failures from empty output -- detect the failure of the command used for such "here-string" assignments?

My guess is though you are reading false INTO $a, it's still not failing because you are just setting $a to false -- Not failing the script.  For instance if you did echo "Will still run" && /bin/false ; echo "boo failed" I am assuming it would act as intended?  (not tested)

@Zak It doesn't set a to false; it sets a to the output of false (which is the empty string).

shopt -s lastpipe; $(false) | read a?

Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 to learn why not to use that set command then then you don't have to worry about such dark corners.

In my actual usage is, the command runs an SQL-query, and the read is used to save the different columns of the resulting row in different variables. Using read var1 var2 ... va2N <<< $(command) appears to be the way to do it... I just want the script to stop, if the command were to ever fail.

That's simple, store the string.
set -euo pipefail

tmp=$(false)
read -r a <<<"$tmp"

echo Hi there: '>'"$a"'<'

Normally, the exit status of an assignment is 0, unless there is one or more command substitutions in the right-hand side, in which case the exit status is the exit status of the last command substitution.
The exit status of the command substitution doesn't affect the exit status of read, though, when it appears in a here string.

Note: In read command, you'd better enclosing $tmp in double-quotes!

Hi @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Note that it doesn't matter in this specific case - the result of expansion of word after <<< does not undergo expansions. But let's do it anyway to promote good practices.

An alternative approach:

capture the subcommand output to a variable; this should maintain the return code at the parent level where the set -e can catch it
then read the variable into the array

Modifying OP's current code:
set -eu -o pipefail

result=$(false)

read -r a <<< "${result}"

echo Hi there: '>'$a'<'

For result=$(false) no output is generated.
For result=$(true) the following is output: Hi there: ><
See this SuperUser Q&A for more details

Thanks, but why do you use quotes and curly braces around $result?

Your script doesn't stop after the second line because of how Bash handles errors in command substitutions. When you use $(...), if the command inside fails, Bash doesn't exit, even with set -e. So when false runs inside $(false), it fails, but the script keeps going.
The read a <<< $(false) line ends up assigning an empty string to a because $(false) produces nothing. That's why your script prints Hi there: ><, showing that a is empty.
You need a way to catch the failure of the command inside $(...). Since set -e doesn't catch it you have to check the command's exit status yourself. One way is to run the command first, check if it succeeded, and then assign its output.
So, to reliably detect if the command failed or just returned an empty string you should separate the command execution from the assignment. If the command fails your script can exit or handle the error properly.

set -e will stop the script after an actual failure --  You haven't failed anything with your script.  You successfully are reading false INTO $a ..  So you are successfully setting $a to false.  This is a successful line.
If you were to actually create a failure for example calling /bin/false this should create a true script failure and exit the way you are intending ..  And there is no need to separate your flags .. You can run them together -euo
set -euo pipefail

echo "Will still run" && /bin/false ; 

echo "boo failed"

